# How do I win on the Contamination gamemode in Splitgate?

Tags: splitgate-arena-warfare

I have a weekly challenge to win 3 matches of Contamination. It's basically infected from other games, where a team of Zombies only have bats and portals, attacking survivors with Carbines, Shotguns, and no portals.

I have won rounds as both the Zombies and Survivors, but the counter for the challenge has not increased. How do I win rounds of Contamination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is based on the number of kills you get during those three rounds, both as human and zombie, so it pays to be aggressive as a human and not always hide in an obscure part of the map.

Comment: That... is very silly. But thanks!